# AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant from oauth2client

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I am creating a script that will download files for a particular Google Apps user using Google-api-python-client At first I'm trying to get the list of files that a users account contain.
I'm following the example given in the link https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

code block are given below

**authorization of the client by the user**

```
def authorize_application(request):

    #setting flow to get permission and code 
    flow = OAuth2WebServerFlow(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI, ACCESS_TYPE)
    authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()

    code = request.GET.get('code', '')

    if code:
        #import ipdb
        #ipdb.set_trace()
    #setting flow step2 to exchage code for access token    
        credential = flow.step2_exchange(code)

    #initialising httplib2 instance and building a DriveAPI service
        http = httplib2.Http()
        http = credential.authorize(http)
        drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

        # getting user's data
    about = drive_service.about().get().execute()
        user_info = about.get('user')
        email = user_info.get('emailAddress')
        request.session['username'] = email[0:email.index('@')]
        username = request.session['username']
        #import ipdb
        #ipdb.set_trace()
        #creating a Django user object 
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, email=email)

    #saving credentials to database 
        if created == True: 
            storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
            storage.put(credential)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/download/')
        else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/download/')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(authorize_url)
```

**getting list of files in users Drive**

```
def download_file(request):

    #import ipdb
    #ipdb.set_trace()

    username = request.session['username']
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)

    storage = Storage(CredentialsModel, 'id', user, 'credential')
    credential = storage.get()

    access_token = credential.access_token

    http = httplib2.Http()
    http = credential.authorize(http)
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

    result = []
    page_token = access_token

    while True:

    try:
        param = {}
            if page_token:
                param['pageToken'] = page_token
            files = drive_service.files().list(**param).execute()

            result.extend(files['items'])
                page_token = files.get('nextPageToken')

        if not page_token:
        break
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print 'An error occured: %s' % error
        break

    return HttpResponse(result)
```

It's saving and retrieving the credential from database but its giving error "AccessTokenRefreshError: invalid_grant" at 
files = drive_service.files().list(**param).execute() of download_file()

What I'm doing wrong? please suggest the right way.

Comment: Hey @Vishnu, what scope are you using ?

Comment: Thanks Thibault for concening my question. I'm using these two scopes 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',

Answer (score 1):

**(Feb 2017)** Not sure what your problem is/was, but a couple of things: 1) the Drive API has a [newer version](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2015/12/a-leaner-and-faster-google-drive-api.html) (v3), and 2) the auth code you used can now be simplified significantly with the recent updates in the Google APIs Client Library. (Make sure you update your Python libraries with `pip install -U google-api-python-client` [or `pip3` for Python 3].)

Below's a working solution -- tell me if it works for you -- that I wrote up in [this blog post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2014/11/authorized-google-api-access-from-python.html) and in [this video](http://youtu.be/Z5G0luBohCg?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=4). I left out the `about()` call to get the user info, but I divide the code up into the same 2 sections you had above, but as you can see, with much less code:

**authorization of the client by the user**

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

**getting list of files in users Drive** (the 1st 100 files)

```
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
files = DRIVE.files().list().execute().get('files', [])
for f in files:
    print(f['name'], f['mimeType'])
```

If you want to learn more about using the Drive API, here are some additional resources (videos, blog posts, etc.) I've created:

- [Google Drive: Uploading & Downloading Files](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) video plus "Poor man's plain text to PDF converter" code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) (*)
- Exporting a Google Sheet as CSV [blog post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html) only

(*) - TL;DR: upload plain text file to Drive, import/convert to Google Docs format, then export that Doc as PDF. Post above uses Drive API v2 like your code sample; [this follow-up post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) describes migrating it to Drive API v3, and here's a [developer video](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) combining both "poor man's converter" posts.